# Is a bialgebra pairing of Hopf algebras automatically a Hopf pairing?

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras

The following question came up in the course on Quantum Groups here at UC Berkeley.  (If you care, I have been TeXing [uneditted lecture notes](http://math.berkeley.edu/~theojf/QuantumGroups10.pdf).)

Let $X,Y$ be (infinite-dimensional) [Hopf algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_algebra) over a ground field $\mathbb F$.  A linear map $\langle,\rangle : X\otimes Y \to \mathbb F$ is a **bialgebra pairing** if $\langle x,y_1y_2 \rangle = \langle \Delta x,y_1\otimes y_2\rangle$ and $\langle x_1x_2,y\rangle = \langle x_1\otimes x_2,\Delta y\rangle$ for all $x,x_1,x_2 \in X$ and $y,y_1,y_2 \in Y$.  (You must pick a convention of how to define the pairing $\langle,\rangle : X^{\otimes 2} \otimes Y^{\otimes 2} \to \mathbb F$.)  And we also demand that $\langle 1,- \rangle = \epsilon_Y$ and $\langle -,1\rangle = \epsilon_X$, but this might follow from the previous conditions.  (See edit.)

A bialgebra pairing is **Hopf** if it also respects the antipode: $\langle S(x),y \rangle = \langle x,S(y)\rangle$.  A pairing $\langle,\rangle : X\otimes Y \to \mathbb F$ is **nondegenerate** if each of the the induced maps $X \to Y^*$ and $Y \to X^*$ has trivial kernel.

> **Question:** Is a (nondegenerate) bialgebra pairing of Hopf algebras necessarily Hopf?  (Does it depend on whether the pairing is nondegenerate?)

My intuition is that regardless of the nondegeneracy, the answer is "Yes": my motivation is that a bialgebra homomorphism between Hopf algebras automatically respects the antipode.  But we were unable to make this into a proof in the infinite-dimensional case.

**Edit:** If $\langle,\rangle: X\otimes Y \to \mathbb F$ is nondegenerate, then it is true that as soon as it satisfies $\langle x,y_1y_2 \rangle = \langle \Delta x,y_1\otimes y_2\rangle$ and $\langle x_1x_2,y\rangle = \langle x_1\otimes x_2,\Delta y\rangle$, so that the induced maps $X \to Y^*$ and $Y \to X^*$ are (possibly non-unital) algebra homomorphisms, then it also satisfies $\langle 1,- \rangle = \epsilon_Y$ and $\langle -,1\rangle = \epsilon_X$, so that the algebra homomorphism are actually unital.  But I think that this does require that the pairing be nondegenerate.  At least, I don't see how to prove it without the nondegeneracy assumption.  So probably the nondegeneracy is required for the statement about antipodes as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theo,

I think one can argue like this in the case of a non-degenerate pairing.  I didn't check everything here carefully, so don't believe it unless you confirm it yourself.

One has from the pairing an inclusion of $i:X\hookrightarrow Y^*$. One has two maps on $i(X)$, $S_X$, and $S_Y^*|_{i(X)}$.  Both of these satisfy the axioms of an antipode on $i(X)$ (which we can check by pairing with elements of $Y$), so they must agree, as desired, since being a Hopf algebra is a property, not a structure.

I'll think about the degenerate situation.  My guess is that it's not true, but I don't know.

Comment: That's the type of argument we were trying to construct.  But, come to think of it, I'm not sure what is the map `$S^*_Y|_{i(X)}$`.  A priori, it is a map `$i(X) \to Y^*$`.  But I don't think it automatically factors through $i(X)$?

Comment: Maybe the point is to do the following.  On the space of functions `$X \to Y^*$` there is the convolution product, given by `$f*g = m_{Y^*} \circ (f\otimes g) \circ \Delta_X$`.  Then you will argue that both `$i\circ S_X$` and `$S^*_Y \circ i$` are two-sided inverses for `$i: X \to Y^*$`, and so must agree.

Comment: Continuing in the train of thought from the previous comment, it's clear that `$i\circ S_X$` is a two-sided inverse for $i$ just as soon as $i$ is an algebra homomorphism, using the Hopf identities.  As for `$S_Y^* \circ i$`, we want to check that `$m_{Y^*} \circ ((S_Y^* \otimes i) \otimes i) \circ \Delta_X$` is `$1_{Y^*} \circ \epsilon_X$`.  But `$m_{Y^*} \circ ((S_Y^* \otimes i) \otimes i) \circ \Delta_X = m_{Y^*} \circ (S_Y^* \otimes \text{id}) \circ (i\otimes i) \circ \Delta_X = \bigl( (S_Y \otimes \text{id}) \circ \Delta_Y \bigr)^* \circ (i\otimes i) \circ \Delta_X$`.

Comment: (continued) So if `$(i\otimes i) \circ \Delta_X = m_Y^* \circ i$`, we'd be done.  And I think this is the other axiom to be a bialgebra pairing.  (Oh, and I just noticed an error, which is that both times that I wrote "`$(S_Y^* \otimes i)$`" I meant "`$S_Y^* \circ i$`".  And there's no "edit" for comments until at least the next upgrade.)

Comment: Ok, so I think even without any nondegeneracy assumptions, just that `$X \to Y^*$` and `$Y \to X^*$` are both unital algebra homomorphisms, we have that `$i \circ S_X = S_Y^* \circ i$`, which in terms of elements of $X,Y$ is `$\langle S(x),y\rangle = \langle x,S(y)\rangle$`.  So I'm happy, and I think I'll accept your answer.  But do let me know if I've made an error.

Comment: Well, it seems a stretch to accept my answer, since I overlooked such an obvious point, whereas your comments fill this out with what I would argue is the main point (which I had missed).  But I won't argue =].

Answer (score 4):

Hi

I was in class when the question came up, and I remember the discussion on whether a bialgebra pairing of $A$ and $B$ always induces a bialgebra map $A\to B^\circ$. You guys tricked me back then :): it is, in fact, true. In other words, a bialgebra pairing is *always* (regardless of (non)degeneracy) exactly the same thing as a bialgebra map from one of the two bialgebras to the finite dual of the other.

I'm going to view the elements of $a$ as linear maps on $B$ via the pairing. We want to show that the map from $A$ to the dual of $B$ induced by the pairing actually lands in $B^\circ$.

This is pretty clear using the following characterization of the finite dual: $B^\circ$ is precisely the set of $f\in B^*$ for which one can find finitely many $g_i,h_i\in B^*$ such that $f(xy)=\sum_ig_i(x)h_i(y)$ (for all $x,y\in B$). It follows immediately from the bialgebra pairing conditions that any $a\in A$ satisfies this property: if, say $\Delta(a)=\sum_i a'_i\otimes a''_i$, then take $g_i=a'_i$ and $h_i=a''_i$.

Answer (score 0):

The induced map $X \to Y^\ast$ is a map of bialgebras, and therefore a map of Hopf algebras. So it takes $S(x)$ to $\langle x, S(-) \rangle$ as desired. This seems too simple, though, so something might be wrong. Is the antipode of the dual Hopf algebra not what I think it is?

Comment: If Y is not finite dimensional, one cannot define a bialgebra structure on $Y^*$ a priori.  The coproduct on $Y$ defines a product on $Y^*$; however the product on $Y$ does not yield a coproduct on $Y^*$.  This is because $Y^*\otimes Y^*\subset(Y\otimes Y)^*$ but not conversely.

Comment: Right.  The question is trivial for $Y$ finite-dimensional, but as DJ says, if $Y$ is infinite-dimensional, then `$Y^*$` is not a bialgebra, and the map `$X \to Y^*$` is only an algebra homomorphism.  There is a canonical __Hopf dual__ for any Hopf algebra, defined by `$Y^\circ = \{\mu \in Y^* \text{s.t. } m^*(\mu) \in Y^* \otimes Y^*\}$`, where `$m^*: Y^* \to (Y \otimes Y)^*$` is dual to the multiplication map.  Then $Y^\circ$ is Hopf, a result I think is due to Drinfel'd.  But we were not sure whether a bialgebra pairing induces a bialg homo $X \to Y^\circ$.  If it does, we're done.